# Dictionaries in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

### Heading Does anyone know how can I map a dictionary in React js ?

```
export class ServiceFeatures extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {dict: {'awesome': ['wow','alo'], 'great': ['ano', 'alo' ]}}
    }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.dict.map((name, features) => (
              <Services categories={features}></Services>
          ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map over the keys of an object using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
return (
    <div>
        {
          Object.keys(this.state.dict).map(name => (
            <Services categories={this.state.dict[name]}></Services>
          ))
        }
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your data here is the solution to iterate it.

```
var object= this.state.dict;

for (var property in object) {//properties in your dict
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    console.log("attr: "+ property); 
    object[property].map(function(item,index){ // iterate list items of each attribute
              console.log("list item : "+item);
            });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
attr: awesome
 list item : wow
 list item : alo
attr: great
 list item : ano
 list item : alo
```

reference: [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Map syntax of EcmaScript6. 
From the Mozilla developer docs:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 'zero'); myMap.set(1, 'one'); 
for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value); 
} 
// 0 = zero
// 1 = one
```